# How to get the a column for the frequency of items sold per Clients?

Tags: python, loops, frequency

How do I calculate the frequency of the `ItemSold` grouped by each `ClientID` and create the new column for that frequency?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
data = {'ClientId': ['1','2','3','4','2','2','1','4'],
        'QuantitySold': ['5','10','6','7','5','10','8','7']
       }
```

Expected Output:

```
Client Id     QuantitySold     FrequencySold
1             5                0.385
2             10               0.4
3             6                1
4             7                0.5
2             5                0.2
2             10               0.4
1             8                0.615
4             7                0.5
```

I have found a solution for the calculation but can't manage to create the new column `FrequencySold`.

Working code:

```
import collections
totals = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c, q in zip(data["ClientId"], data["QuantitySold"]):
    totals[c] += int(q)
# defaultdict(int, {'1': 13, '2': 25, '3': 6, '4': 14})

for c, q in zip(data["ClientId"], data["QuantitySold"]):
    print(c, q, int(q)/totals[c])
```

How do I create the new column based on the loop?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> data = {'ClientId': ['1','2','3','4','2','2','1','4'],
...         'QuantitySold': ['5','10','6','7','5','10','8','7']
...        }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>>
>>> df['FrequencySold'] = df.groupby('ClientId')['QuantitySold'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int) / x.astype(int).sum())
>>> df
  ClientId QuantitySold  FrequencySold
0        1            5       0.384615
1        2           10       0.400000
2        3            6       1.000000
3        4            7       0.500000
4        2            5       0.200000
5        2           10       0.400000
6        1            8       0.615385
7        4            7       0.500000
```